# Implementing Sized trait

Tags: rust, traits

Created a simple struct that implements Sized trait.

```
struct FixedIndividual<T: Sized,A: cmp::Ord, >{
    chromosome: T,
    score: Option<A>,
}
impl<T: Sized, A: cmp::Ord> FixedIndividual<T,A>{
    fn new(chromosome: T) -> Self{
        FixedIndividual { chromosome , score: None}
    }
}
```

However, I've managed to create an instance that includes Vec(implement only ?Size),

```
 #[test]
    fn init_vector(){
        let chromosome: Vec<i32> = vec![1,2,3,4,5];
        let chromosome_cpy = chromosome.clone();
        let indv:FixedIndividual<Vec<i32>, OrderedFloat<f64>> = FixedIndividual::new(chromosome);
        assert_eq!(indv.score, None);
        assert_eq!( indv.chromosome
                    .iter()
                    .zip(chromosome_cpy.iter())
                    .all(|(a,b)| a == b ), true);
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Created a simple struct that implements Sized trait.

Your bounds are useless, generic bounds are `Sized` by default, you have to opt out of it.

> However, I've managed to create an instance that includes Vec(implement only ?Size),

Not sure where you got that idea, and `?Sized` is not a trait, it's only a bound which means the type (or function) is *sizedness-agnostic*. That doesn't imply it's unsized itself. For instance `Box<T>` has `T: ?Sized`, meaning `T` may be sized or unsized. `Box` is sized either way.

A type being unsized means it implements `!Sized`, which rather few types do.

Answer (score 1):

That's fine because `Vec`s are `Sized`, like almost all `struct` values. The actual `Vec` value does not contain its elements, but instead references them, so it has a defined, constant size no matter how many elements there are, similar to how a pointer is stored in an integer value. You may also have confused vecs with slices, such as `[i32]`, which are `?Sized`.

Comment: is there a trait for only sized type (known at compile time) or a way to distinguish between types like i32,f32....  and vec,Maps,Iter and so on ?

Comment: @Guy-Arieli what is the difference you're trying to capture in a trait? The sizes of pointers, and other objects that act like pointers, are known at compile time. What might not be known at compile time is the total memory usage they refer to, but why would you need to distinguish that with a trait?

Comment: @Guy-Arieli is something not working right for you in the code you posted? If so, what? The code you posted wouldn't make sense with `i32` instead of `Vec<i32>`, because an `i32` is only one value, there's nothing to iterate.

Comment: I'm trying to build a generic GA library,  the mutation function mostly works for a list-like object, so I want to differ between the two in order to create a module for each one.

Comment: @Guy-Arieli you can always create different modules. You can create as many modules as you like. That doesn't answer the question of, "what code is not working? how is it not working?"